# How to add a back button to createMaterialTopTabNavigator (React Navigator)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So I'm not too familiar with React Navigation but I'm making some progress. One thing I'm having trouble of figuring out is adding a back button to a tab navigator.

So on my main screen, I have a top tab navigator that allows the user to switch between the Details screen and the Chat screen. Kinda looks like:

[-----[ Chat ] [ Details ]-----]

I can turn on header mode, but it adds a header to the top of the tab nav, so it looks like:

[ < -----------------------------]

[-----[ Chat ] [ Details ]-----]

That's a lot of white space in the header. I figured I could easily add the back button to the tab nav, but having a hard time figuring out how.

Here's the code I'm trying out with. Thanks for the help!

```
const chatStack = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Details: {
      screen: connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps,
      )(ChatDetails),
    },
    Chat: {
      screen: connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps,
      )(ChatWindow),
    },
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      style: styles.chatTabBar,
    },
  },
)

export default createStackNavigator(
  {
    ShowMessages: {
      screen: connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps,
      )(MessageScreen),
    },
    ChatWindow: chatStack,
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
  },
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can custom the `tarBarComponent`.

```
import {
    createMaterialTopTabNavigator,
    MaterialTopTabBar,
    HeaderBackButton
} from 'react-navigation';

createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Archive: {
        screen: ArchiveScreen,
    },
    Report: {
        screen: ReportScreen,
    }
}, {
    tabBarComponent: props => {
        return ( <
            View style = {
                {
                    flexDirection: 'row'
                }
            } >
            <
            HeaderBackButton { ...props
            }
            onPress = {
                () => {
                    props.navigation.navigate('Home');
                }
            }
            /> <
            MaterialTopTabBar { ...props
            }
            style = {
                {
                    flex: 1,
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
                }
            }
            /> <
            /View>
        );
    },
});
```

Comment: This is nice, however MaterialTopTabBar renders TabBar that still uses full screen width, which causes the tabs to go out of view on the right side.